# How to Display recent Posts in WordPress blog home page only when a link is clicked

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Need to do the following process when a particular tab is clicked in wordpress in blog home page

Need to display using ajax

For example,

There are three tabs saying They like , Recent ,Popular , All in blog home page

1)When "They like" tab is clicked -> In the blog home page, need to display the latest 16 posts from the blog members they like.

2)When "Recent" tab is clicked, need to perform the following tasks
In the content area, need to display the latest 16 posts from the authors.

3)When "Popular" tab is clicked, need to perform the following tasks
In the content area, need to display the popular 16 posts from the authors.

4)When "All" tab is clicked 
need to display all the post from the blog with pagination underneath the content area.

Answer (score 0):

you have recent post with this

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

- read manual http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

you can create query posts, for example you want have recent tag or date or any thing

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=5');
```

or

```
global $query_string;
parse_str( $query_string, $args );
$args[post_type] = array( 'post', 'video' );
query_posts( $args );
```

or

```
query_posts( 'cat=1&tag=apples' );
```

- read manual http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

also see wp plug-ins and then customize in:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/u-more-recent-posts/screenshots/

Comment: Thanks Efazati, i will go through the above links and let you know

Comment: I have gone through the links but unable to fix

Comment: actually i need to display the posts of "They like posts" , "Recent posts" ,"Popular posts" ," All posts " of the authors when the tabs "They like" , "Recent" ,"Popular" ," All " is clicked, in the blog home page

Comment: yo can create page like index.php in template named recent.php, popular.php and other and then use these query

Comment: i have done the same step1:created recent.php,they-like.php,popular.php and all.php as a template 
and written to fetch the recent post from the posts of the authors and popular post from the posts of the authors and all posts from the posts of the authors
step2:And assigned the link for the tabs using custom menu,Thanks a lot